# Understanding ramification points of algebraic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

In order to introduce the problem, let us consider the algebraic function $\sqrt{z}$ on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. It is branched at $0$: in fact choosing a branch of it and performing an analytic continuation along a loop wrapping around $0$ it changes sign.

Now, let us consider an algebraic function $f(z)$ which is obtained as solution of an algebraic equation
$$F(z,w):=w^n + a_1(z)w^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{n-1}(z)w + a_n(z)=0,$$
where the coefficients $a_i(z)$ are given meromorphic functions. What can we say about the branch points of $\sqrt{f(z)}$? In particular, is $\sqrt{f(z)}$ branched at the zeros of $f(z)$? If $P\in \mathbb{C}$ is such that $f(P)=0$, is it true that $\sqrt{f(z)}$ changes sign performing an analytic continuation along a loop which wraps around $P$?

One of the things that makes me confused is the case of $\sqrt{z^2}$.

As an example, let us consider the algebraic function $$\sqrt{f(z)}, \qquad \textrm{ where } \qquad f(z)=\sqrt{z} + \sqrt{z-1} + \sqrt{z-2}.$$ By considering the equation $f(z)=0$ we obtain the quadratic equation $3z^2-6z-1=0$, which has solutions $$z_1=1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, \qquad z_2=1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}.$$ These solutions are zeros for some branch of $f(z)$. Is $\sqrt{f(z)}$ branched at $z_1, z_2$? How can I check this?